# Change reading interval of sensor using php

Tags: php, mysql, arduino

So, I have arduino code like this :

```
#include <Ethernet.h>
#include <SPI.h> m 
#include "kSeries.h"

kSeries K_30(8,9);


byte mac[] = { 0xDE, 0xAD, 0xBE, 0xEF, 0xFE, 0xED };
byte ip[] = { 192, 168, 1, 229 };
byte gateway[] = { 192, 168, 1, 1 };
byte server[] = { 192, 168, 1, 138 }; // alamat host Server
String location = "GET http://192.168.1.138/SIMON/datasetiapdetik.php?";
//String location = "POST /alvin/datasetiapdetik.php?";
String host = "Host:  192.168.1.138";

EthernetClient client;

void setup()
{
  Ethernet.begin(mac, ip);
  Serial.begin(9600);
  Serial.println("connecting...");
}

void loop()
{
   double co2 = K_30.getCO2('p');
  // Print the value on Serial
  Serial.print(co2);
  Serial.println("ppm \t");



String data;
  data+="";
  data+="device=arduino";
  data+="&A0=";data+=co2;
  data+="&submit=Submit";
  Serial.print(data);
while (client.connect(server, 80)) {
    Serial.println("Sending data..");


    //lokasi halaman atau form 
    client.print(location);
    client.print(data);
    client.println("HTTP/1.1");
    client.println(host);
    //client.println("Connection: close");
    //char web=client.read();
    Serial.print(location);
    Serial.print(data);

    client.stop();  
  }
  /*
  if (!client.connected()) {
    Serial.println();
    Serial.println("disconnecting.");
    client.stop();
  delay(50);
  }*/
  delay(2000);
}
```

and the php code like this :

```
<?php
include "config/koneksi.php";
error_reporting(0); 
date_default_timezone_set('Asia/Jakarta');
// EDIT: Your mysql database account information
$tablename = "input";
$localhost = "localhost";
$date = date('y-m-d');
$waktu = date('H:i');
$tanggal = date('y-m-d');
$menit = date('i');


    //Create tabel everyday
    $sql = "\n"
    . " CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `input` ( `ID` bigint(20) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT ,\n"
    . " `date` date NOT NULL ,\n"
    . " `time` time NOT NULL,\n"
    . " `device` text NOT NULL ,\n"
    . " `A0` int( 11 ) NOT NULL ,\n"
    . " PRIMARY KEY ( `ID` ) ) ENGINE = InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET = latin1;";
    $create = mysql_query($sql);    


$sql = "SELECT * 
    FROM `$tablename` 
    WHERE `date`='$date' and `time`='$waktu'
    ";

    $uji = mysql_num_rows(mysql_query($sql));

if ($menit % 1 == 0 and $uji < 1)   {   
$query1 = "INSERT INTO `input` (date,time,device,A0 VALUES ('$date','$waktu','$_GET[device]','$_GET[A0]')";
    $result = mysql_query($query1);
    }
else {  

}


    echo 'GET  = ' . htmlspecialchars($_GET["device"]) . '!<br>';
    echo 'GET  = ' . htmlspecialchars($_GET["A0"]) . '!<br>';



echo "<h1>Sistem Monitoring Siap!!</h1>";
echo `\n`;

?>
```

it read the data every minute and its fine. But when I change the $menit % 1 to % 5, it didn't work. How I change the interval so i can read the data every 5 minute ? Thanks

Comment: how is this run perhaps its timing out - have you considered a cronjob?

Comment: I am new for this stuff. How i change the code from above ? Or perhaps you can give me a new one ?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe feasible:
You want to store only one value per time interval. Let's assume the interval to be 5 minutes. So e.g. every request that comes in between 6:40:00 and 6:44:59 would be in the "time slot" 6:40. And every request between 6:45:00 and 6:49:59 in the 6:45 "slot".
That's easy to achieve. You set the seconds to zero and substract from the minutes (minutes modulo interval), e.g. a request comes in at 6:43 -> minutes = 43 - (43%5) = 43-3 = 40.
A request comes in at 6:44 -> minutes = 44 - (44%5) = 44-4 = 40.
A request comes in at 6:45 -> minutes = 45 - (45%5) = 45-0 = 45.
And so on and on.

Now you add a [unique index](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/constraint-primary-key.html) to your mysql table, like so

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `input` (
    `ID` bigint(20) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    `date` date NOT NULL,
    `time` time NOT NULL,
    `device` VARCHAR(128) NOT NULL,
    `A0` int( 11 ) NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY ( `ID` ),
    UNIQUE KEY(`date`,`time`)
) ENGINE = InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET = latin1
```

The `UNIQUE KEY(`date`,`time`)`* won't allow a second record with the same date+time, so once a record for one "time slot" is in the table any subsequent INSERT for the same "time slot" will fail (or be ignored).
The error code you would get back in such case is [1022 ER_DUP_KEY](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/error-messages-server.html#error_er_dup_key) and you could test for that specific error code if you like. If you don't you could just send an `INSERT IGNORE INTO ...` query. If there's a unique index conflict, that INSERT is just silently ignored.

The mysql_* extension [is deprecated](http://docs.php.net/manual/en/intro.mysql.php) and will be removed with the upcoming release 7 of php. So I won't give you a mysql_* example but one using [PDO](http://docs.php.net/pdo) and [prepared statements](http://docs.php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepared-statements.php) instead (untested, though).

```
<?php
define('INTERVAL_MINUTES', 5);

include "config/koneksi.php";
date_default_timezone_set('Asia/Jakarta');

$pdo = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=test;charset=utf8', 'localonly', 'localonly', array(
    PDO::ATTR_EMULATE_PREPARES=>false,
    PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_DIRECT_QUERY=>false,
    PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE=>PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION
));

$pdo->exec('
    CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `input` (
        `ID` bigint(20) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
        `date` date NOT NULL,
        `time` time NOT NULL,
        `device` VARCHAR(128) NOT NULL,
        `A0` int( 11 ) NOT NULL,
        PRIMARY KEY ( `ID` ),
        UNIQUE KEY(`date`,`time`,`device`)
    ) ENGINE = InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET = latin1
');


$ts = getdate();
// "adjusting" to the time slot
$ts['minutes'] = $ts['minutes'] - ($ts['minutes']%INTERVAL_MINUTES);

$stmt = $pdo->prepare('
    INSERT IGNORE INTO
        `input`
        (`date`,`time`,`device`,`A0`)
    VALUES
        (:date,:time,:device,:A0)
');

$params = array(
    'date'=>sprintf('%04d-%02d-%02d', $ts['year'], $ts['month'], $ts['mday']),
    'time'=>$time = sprintf('%02d:%02d:00', $ts['hours'], $ts['minutes']),
    'device'=>$_GET['device'],
    'A0'=>$_GET['A0']
);

$stmt->execute($params);
```

edit: * on second thought you probably want `UNIQUE KEY(date,time,device)` - so that multiple devices can *each* insert one record per time slot....
and another edit: For this to be working as intended INTERVAL_MINUTES must be a divisor of 60. We probably have 60 minutes to an hour because 60 has so many divisors (1,2,3,4,5,6,10,12,15,20,30,60), so I hope that's ok....